# Spring RestTemplate: post both an image and an object at the same time

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

My users can post a photo of a food stuff and a post of what the food stuff is about to my server.

For example, let say, someone sees something delicious, snaps a picture of it and then writes "Tasty!" underneath the picture. The photo is sent to the server, and the message "Tasty!" including the users name, date, location etc is sent in an object called "Post" to my server using one api call.

I have written the following code on my android side:

```
    final String url = Constants.POST_PICS;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = RestClientConfig.getRestTemplate(context, true);
    //adding StringHttpMessageConverter, formHttpMessageConverter and MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to restTemplate
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(formHttpMessageConverter);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    //putting both objects into a map
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    map.add("image", new FileSystemResource(file));
    map.add("post", post);
    HttpHeaders imageHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    //setting content type to multipart as the image is a multipart file
    imageHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> imageEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, imageHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<Post> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, imageEntity, Post.class);
    return response.getBody();
```

This is the code on the Spring side:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadpostpic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Post uploadPostWithPic(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile srcFile,
                                  @RequestParam("post") Post post) {
    return serviceGateway.uploadPostWithPic(srcFile, post);
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> An exception occurred during request network execution :Could not
>   write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type
>   [Model.Post]
>
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for
>   request type [Model.Post]

I suspect it is to do with the content-type being set to MULTIPART_FORM_DATA but I need it set to this as I need to transfer the picture up to the server.

Is it even possible to transfer a multipart file and another object upstream using restTemplate at the same time?

EDIT:

I have looked at these posts:

[Resttemplate form/multipart: image + JSON in POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184215/resttemplate-form-multipart-image-json-in-post)

[Sending Multipart File as POST parameters with RestTemplate requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118670/sending-multipart-file-as-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests)

And tried according to their guidance this code:

```
    final String url = Constants.POST_PIC;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());

    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    formHttpMessageConverter.addPartConverter(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    formHttpMessageConverter.addPartConverter(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter()); // This is hope driven programming
    formHttpMessageConverter.addPartConverter(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(formHttpMessageConverter);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartRequest = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) imageFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;

    //convert file into array of bytes
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
    fileInputStream.read(bFile);
    fileInputStream.close();

    ByteArrayResource bytes = new ByteArrayResource(bFile) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return "file.jpg";
        }
    };

    //post portion of the multipartRequest
    HttpHeaders xHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    xHeader.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Post> xPart = new HttpEntity<>(post, xHeader);
    multipartRequest.add("post", xPart);

    //picture portion of the multipartRequest
    HttpHeaders pictureHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    pictureHeader.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    HttpEntity<ByteArrayResource> picturePart = new HttpEntity<>(bytes, pictureHeader);
    multipartRequest.add("srcFile", picturePart);

    //adding both the post and picture portion to one httpentity for transmitting to server
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA); 
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(multipartRequest, header);
    return restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, Post.class);
```

On the other side, the post = null and I'm not sure why it is null.

This is all I'm trying to do on the server side:

```
public Post uploadPostPic(MultipartFile srcFile, Post post) {
    Post savedPost = repo.save(post);
 }
```

I'm saving it into my repository and the error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must not be null!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
Send jsonString here and later convert it to object using objectwriter.Let me know if you need more explanation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadMultipleFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadMultipleFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String[] names,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files) {

        if (files.length != names.length)
            return "Mandatory information missing";

        String message = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            MultipartFile file = files[i];
            String name = names[i];
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                logger.info("Server File Location="
                        + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

                message = message + "You successfully uploaded file=" + name
                        + "<br />";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

Eventually, I had to make use of the jsonString to solve my problem. It is not ideal as the url will end up becoming very long but it is the quickest way to solve my problem:

Please have a look at the advice from mykong on how to transform your object to jsonString and retransform them back into objects:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Staff obj = new Staff();

//Object to JSON in String
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);

//JSON from String to Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: I prefer not to do this if Spring has this feature built in automatically/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a registered HttpMessageConverter for your Post class. You will probably have to register an HttpMessageConverter for MultiValueMap.

Comment: Can the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() not map it correctly to a json object?

Comment: Frankly, I would expect so, if your Post has the Jackson annotations. I assume you have registered a Converter in Spring ConversionService for your '@RequestParam("post") Post post'. I would try to replace your Post class with String and see whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

oookay,I faced the same problem few weeks ago. First of all to be clear what `multipart/form-data` content-type means:

> A "multipart/form-data" message contains a series of parts, each
>   representing a successful control.
>
> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful
>   control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set

in simple words, with multipart form-data you can send different content-types of data to server. here is a sample:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: __atuvc=34%7C7; permanent=0; _gitlab_session=226ad8a0be43681acf38c2fab9497240; __profilin=p%3Dt; request_method=GET
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Length: 554

-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

text default
-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Content of a.txt.

-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="a.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html><title>Content of a.html.</title>

-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266--
```

here is a sample of sending three different sets - the first one is `binary data` the second one is `plain text` and the third one is `html` and they are separated by boundary.

now how working `Spring's RestTemplate` ?

when you set the request header to `multipart/form-data` , resttemplate will pick up appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` from registered message converters which for `multipart/form-data` will be `FormHttpMessageConverter` see doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html).

But `FormHttpMessageConverter` have a property of `partConverters` and they are converters registered for the `FormHttpMessageConverter` and by default they are (string,bytearray and resource). here is a source code of the constructor ;)

```
public FormHttpMessageConverter() {
    this.supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    this.supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    this.partConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringHttpMessageConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
    this.partConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
    this.partConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
}
```

with simply words, `FormHttpMessageConverter` cannot find correct message converter to write object `Post`. If you want `Post` to be written as JSON you should add `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to `partConverters`.

```
@Produces
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.getMessageConverters().add(0,createFormHttpConverter());
        return template;
    }
 private static HttpMessageConverter<?> createFormHttpConverter(){

        FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        formHttpMessageConverter.setPartConverters(getPartConverters());
        return formHttpMessageConverter;
    }

private static List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getPartConverters(){
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = template.getMessageConverters();
    messageConverters.add(0,converter);
    return messageConverters;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I just tried it out and resttemplate was able to send it out to the server but when it reached the server, the image object was sent successfully, but the post object returned null on the server side. Can you show me what your code looked like on the server side so I can see what you did in terms of RequestMappings, RequestParams etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Spring how to map the request parameters to your objects. You could do this by implementing a custom `HttpMessageConterter` like suggested by Alexander, but I there is a much easier way: Use a command-object (sometimes called form-backing object):

```
public class PostWithPicCommand() {
   public PostWithPic() {}; //Default constructor is required

   //name the variables like the request parameters!
   private Post post;
   private MultipartFile image;

   Getter and Setter!
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadpostpic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Post uploadPostWithPic(PostWithPicCommand postWithPicCommand
      /*no @Param attribte for postWithPicCommand*/) {    
    ....
}
```

And you need to configure/register springs Multipart Resolver, and need to send the request as an multipart request.

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar using this:

```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add("Accept","application/json");     
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
  MultiValueMap<String, Object> map =  new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
  map.add("image", new FileSystemResource(file));
  map.add("post", post);
  HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, headers);
  RestTemplate restTemplate = RestClientConfig.getRestTemplate(context, true);
  restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
  ResponseEntity<Post> response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, Post.class);
```

Comment: I still get the Entity must not be null! error on my server side. Can you please show me your server side code?

Comment: What kind of server do you have? php, groovy, etc?